# flashes of previous SceneKit content

Tags: swift, scenekit

My app alternates "pages" of `SceneKit` content with images and text. When I advance from an image page to a new `SceneKit` page, the content from the previous `SceneKit` page is briefly displayed before being replaced by the new content. Funky.

I'm only using one `SCNScene` and one `SCNView`. When I transition to an image type page, I hide the `SCNView`. To reinstate a new `SceneKit` display I:

1. remove all nodes from the `rootNode`
2. load new node graphs from file
3. add the new node graphs to the `rootNode`
4. unhide the `SCNView`

Evidently the unhiding is asynchronous and I'm seeing the remnants of the earlier scene while the new one is establishing. I'm having a similar issue with `AVPlayer` as well.

In past apps I experienced this same issue with `MPMoviePlayer` and delt with it by displaying a blank view over the movie view and then hiding that on notification that the current movie had loaded. Perhaps I can deal with the `AVPlayer` issue in the same manner but I don't see this applying to `SceneKit`. Even in the case of `AVPlayer` I'd like a better way of dealing with the issue if possible.

edit_1: I've tried Hal's idea of swapping out `SCNScenes` but still get the momentary residual image. I've tried using two `SCNViews` and alternately swapping them out. I've also tried moving the camera past visible elements before exiting the current scene. The `prepareObjects:withCompletion handler` did nothing.

It appears that it's not the nodes nor the `SCNScene` that is persisting but a rendered image of the scene. This is also supported by witnessing this effect with movie players as mentioned above.

edit_2: I tried a mask but like all other attempts it fails. I did have "success" with using an `SCNAction` to move the camera offscreen plus a completion handler to effect changes only after. However, this extends the load time by about 800%! Better to have the ugly "flash".

Comment: It seems like you're working too hard. Why are you not using setting the view's `scene` property to a new scene with your content, or using `presentScene(withTransition:incomingPointOfView:completionHandler:)`? `prepareObject(:shouldAbortBlock)` is worth a look too.

Comment: I'll revisit manipulating the scene, I was hesitant about possible overhead in continually re-adding the camera, lights etc but I guess they pale to some of the models I'm using. I'm avoiding the method you mention, I want compatibility with iOS 8.

Comment: I get the same issue swapping scenes. I don't think this issue is particularily related to working in `SceneKit` having also experiencd it with `AVPlayer` and `MPMoviePlayer`. Thanks to your `presentScene...` pointer, I see a `prepareObjects:withCompletion handler` that I shall try.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something that works but I'm skeptical. I've created a "nullCamera", one that points to an empty field of view. Before switching out my scenes I assign that camera to the `SCNView`. When the new scene loads the principal camera is re-assigned. But I'm nervous about this approach.

I tried this before and it didn't work. It now works because I moved the code upstream (instead of where it seems to belong). But the interveining code has nothing to do with `SceneKit`. It merely parses data for strings, sets color prefs and displays a title in a label. So I'm worried that it's only about timing and I may see the issue again on, say, a faster device. Maybe writing the title to a view element forces a re-display of the `SCNView` too? (Which I couldn't seem to effect with code.)